# What's the antonym for the word 'support' in the following context?

Tags: word-request, word-in-context

What's the antonym for the word 'support' in the following context?

> I am trying to find studies that support or --X-- this claim.

Comment: I might say to my UK cat, 'Your claim that it was the dog that stole the sausages is **undermined** by the paw marks around the fridge'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Weaken" is good.

"Challenge," "undercut," "contradict" (although in that case I'd probably use "confirm" rather than "support"), "rebut," "falsify" (hat tip to Karl Popper), "raise doubts," and "call into question" are some others.

Upon reflection, the most apt word depends on whether you are looking for studies that provide indications or that are definitive.

If you are **not** looking for a definitive study, "support or challenge" seems like a good pair to me.

If you **are** looking for a definitive study, "confirm or falsify" seems like a good pair to me.

As always, word choice ultimately comes down to what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for ***[disprove](https://www.google.com/search?q=refute%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsYtBBk6NeRw4Lb2u65-TCyEOXthHw%3A1659115901083&source=hp&ei=fRnkYseuAoiTgQbH5p54&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYuQnjeJu8pRLdgTwRYyl4NfhAqPy3Qys&oq=refute&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIICAAQgAQQsQMyBQgAEIAEOgQIIxAnOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6DgguEIAEELEDEIMBENQCUABYkwVg9BFoAHAAeACAAWaIAbsDkgEDNS4xmAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz#dobs=disprove)*** or ***[refute](https://www.google.com/search?q=refute%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsYtBBk6NeRw4Lb2u65-TCyEOXthHw%3A1659115901083&source=hp&ei=fRnkYseuAoiTgQbH5p54&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYuQnjeJu8pRLdgTwRYyl4NfhAqPy3Qys&oq=refute&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIICAAQgAQQsQMyBQgAEIAEOgQIIxAnOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6DgguEIAEELEDEIMBENQCUABYkwVg9BFoAHAAeACAAWaIAbsDkgEDNS4xmAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)** this claim*.

Comment: if you downvote, it is polite to say why. Then we have a chance of understanding our mistakes and correcting ourselves. Otherwise your downvote is not constructive.

Comment: I agree. I am going to give you an upvote. There is nothing wrong about your answer.

Comment: @JeffMorrow  Thanks for what this site calls _sportsmanship_ :) This should probably a post on Meta, but I think we forget too often that downvoting is really supposed to HELP, not meant for us to vent our ... whatever.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your answer. I upvoted it immidiately when I saw it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky one. Perhaps *weaken*?